# Typescript Generics: Create factory function which creates different default values based on generic type

Tags: typescript, generics

I have this interface:

```
interface ReturnObject<T> {
  result: T | null;
  messages: string[];
}
```

and a factory function for it with which you can create a `ReturnObject`:

```
const createReturnObject = <T = null>({
  result=null,
  messages=[]
}: {
  result?: T | null,
  messages?: MessageWithInfo[]
}): ReturnObject<T> => {
  return {
    result,
    messages
  };
};
```

When you call this function without a result it sets the default value `null`:

```
const o = createReturnObject<number>({
  messages: ["something went wrong!"]
});

console.log(o.result); // null
```

which works perfectly fine for this example but in this example I would like something different:

```
const o = createReturnObject<number[]>({
  messages: ["Whoops"]
});

console.log(o.result); // null but should be []
```

If an array of some type is passed to this factory function as the generic I would like it to not set the default value `null` but instead an empty array like something like this:

```
const createReturnObject = <T = null>({
  result,
  messages=[]
}: {
  result?: T | null,
  messages?: MessageWithInfo[]
}): ReturnObject<T> => {
  return {
    result: result === undefined 
      ? Array.isArray(T) ? [] : null
      : result,
    messages
  };
};
```

This does not work:

> 'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Is this possible or do I need two seperate functions for that then?

Comment: Types cannot affect runtime behavior: that's one of typescript's goals. If you want to check if the user *intended* to supply an array, either have a boolean flag or a separate function.

Comment: Ok thanks. Should I close the question now?

Comment: I'd say to wait for a bit more before closing the question, as someone else could come along with a bit more insight on how to approach this.

Comment: Ok, you sounded quite confident in your answer and I guess it makes sense. Let’s hope someone else knows a smart solution...

Comment: For more reference on the "types cannot affect runtime behavior" part, see non-goal #5 in [Typescript's design goals](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals): "Add or rely on run-time type information in programs, or emit different code based on the results of the type system."

Comment: @Aplet123 just asked a C# Developer this question. He said that the class is the problem. It does not make sense to let the result of ReturnObject be any and also any[] at the same time. Better would be either separate interfaces or always returning an array which would remove the usage of null which should be avoided.

Comment: Goes pretty much hand in hand with the non-goal #5: "Instead, encourage programming patterns that do not require run-time metadata."